# AMPL variable size set iteration

Tags: mathematical-optimization, ampl

I'm learning AMPL so that I can use it some time later in my programs. I have a small question though that I couldn't find its answer yet.

Suppose I have a **set**, this **set** will contain some subsets, those subsets may differ in their dimensions. For example:

```
set x:= (a,b,c) (a,c) (d,t,r,e,s);
```

and so on ..

Now I want to write a constraint which will have to deal with all elements in each subset (similar to a loop that will iterate between **a**,**b**, and **c** in the first subset, **a** and **c** in the second and so on). The problem is that we don't know the size of each so we can't use the following:

```
set x dimen 3;
subject to constraint {(i,j,k) in x}: "some constraint";
data;
set x:= (a,b,c) (a,c) (d,t,r,e,s);
```

Is there a way to do so? If yes, can you please provide me with some sample code or links to learn from? 
Thanks in advance. Your help is appreciated :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have an indexed set in AMPL which is kind of "set of sets", but all elements of it should have the same dimension:

```
set S;
set T{S} dimen 3; # indexed set with all elements of dimension 3 (triples).
```

However, you can achieve the same effect with parameters:

```
set V ordered;
param values{V} symbolic;

# Indices in values where each subset starts.
set Indices ordered;

data;
param:
V: values :=
 1 a
 2 b
 3 c
 4 a
 5 c
 6 d
 7 t
 8 r
 9 e
10 s;

set Indices := 1 4 6 11;

print {i in Indices: i != last(Indices)}: {j in i .. next(i) - 1} values[j];
```

Running this code will print

```
a b c
a c
d t r e s
```

Comment: Thanks, but in my case, would an asterisk work? I mean, if I already know that the longest subset will have for example dimension 5, can I use (a,b,c, *, *) instead of (a,b,c)? would it have the same meaning? If no, is there any way to pad the subsets to become of dimension 5?

Comment: Asterisk is used for a different purpose - as a placeholder to specify where the next items in data go, but you could designate some other value such as 0 to denote "no data" and pad all the subsets to 5. This should work too.