# AMPL: what's a good way to specify equality constraints for large list of pairs of variable-size sets?

Tags: set, ampl

I'm working on a problem that involves reconciling data that represents estimates of the same system under two different classification hierarchies. I want to enforce the requirement that equivalent classes or groups of classes have the same sum.

For example, say Classification A divides industries into: Agriculture (sheep/cattle), Agriculture (non-sheep/cattle), Mining, Manufacturing (textiles), Manufacturing (non-textiles), ...

Meanwhile, Classification B has a different breakdown: Agriculture, Mining (iron ore), Mining (non-iron-ore), Manufacturing (chemical), Manufacturing (non-chemical), ...

In this case, any total for A_Agric_SheepCattle + A_Agric_NonSheepCattle should match the equivalent total for B_Agric; A_Mining should match B_MiningIronOre + B_Mining_NonIronOre; and A_MFG_Textiles+A_MFG_NonTextiles should match B_MFG_Chemical+B_MFG_NonChemical.

For bonus complication, one category may be involved in multiple equivalencies, e.g. B_Mining_IronOre might be involved in an equivalency with both A_Mining and A_Mining_Metallic.

I will be working with multi-dimensional tables, with this sort of concordance applied to more than one dimension - e.g. I might be compiling data on Industry x Product, so each equivalency will be used in multiple constraints; hence I need an efficient way to define them once and invoke repeatedly, instead of just setting a direct constraint "A_Agric_SheepCattle + A_Agric_NonSheepCattle = B_Agric".

The most natural way to represent this sort of concordance would seem to be as a list of pairs of sets. The catch is that the set sizes will vary - sometimes we have a 1:1 equivalence, sometimes it's "these 5 categories equate to those 7 categories", etc.

I found [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24727818/ampl-variable-size-set-iteration) which offers two answers for dealing with variable-sized sets. One is to define all set members in a single ordered set with indices, then define the starting index for each set within that. However, this seems unwieldy for my problem; both classifications are likely to be long, so I'd need to be hopping between two loooong lists of industries and two looong lists of indices to see a single equivalency. This seems like it would be a nuisance to check, and hard to modify (since any change to membership for one of the early sets changes the index numbers for all following sets).

The other is to define pairs of long fixed-length sets, and then pad each set to the required length with null members.

This would be a much better option for my purposes since it lets me eyeball a single line and see the equivalence that it represents. But it would require a LOT of padding; most of the equivalence groups will be small but a few might be quite large, and everything has to be padded to the size of the largest expected length.

Is there a better approach?